# How can I get a mythic keystone?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In Legion, you can use a mythic keystone to increase the difficulty of mythic dungeons to get better loot.  How can I get a keystone to enable this difficulty?  I've heard the last boss of a mythic dungeon drops one but I haven't found any official sources that confirm this.

Comment: I can't access the information currently [because I'm at work] BUT I believe the answer is in this thread on Battle.net forums - [link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjc1pX_o-7OAhWIbB4KHc6MDEAQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fus.battle.net%2Fwow%2Fen%2Fforum%2Ftopic%2F20743006610&usg=AFQjCNGvxF-SxU2k-aEJ0SSXQq0aeHgudg&sig2=qmSCi6YnS5coEGqlIy6KnA)

Answer (score 1):

> You set a dungeon on Mythic difficulty and enter the dungeon through the dungeon entrance (not Dungeon Finder). Meaning, you need to gather a premade party of 5 yourself or join a party. Best way to find or create one is via the Group Finder in game and click on Premade Groups/Dungeons.
>
> When entering the Mythic Dungeon, you will see a Challenger’s Pedestal. This pole regulates the Mythic plus. If you leave it alone it will be a regular Mythic run. Think of Mythic plus as an upgraded version of Challenge mode.
>
> Completing a Regular Mythic dungeon will reward you with a key. This key will let you do the same Mythic dungeon on level 2 difficulty (1+). Only the same dungeon, no other one.
>
> When completing the mythic 1+ (2nd difficulty) in a certain time, your keystone will upgrade to next level, which is level 3 (+2) and so on and so forth. Each dungeon has its own time point to be able to upgrade your keystone.
>
> When completing a mythic difficulty in time, you will get a loot scaled for the level you completed on (see below). If you failed the timer, you will not get any loot, also your keystone will be depleted.

http://www.worldofmoudi.com/legion-mythic-plus-guide for more info

Comment: This answer is correct, with one caveat that Mythic plus was not available until Tuesday September 13 so no keystones would have dropped before this date.

Comment: actually the correct date is September 20.

Comment: Also keystones will drop for random dungeons, not the one you just completed